# ASP.NET GridView.Databind empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, data-binding

I have a table in sql

```
ID  Team1     Team2   Result
1   Eagle     Eagle   —
2   Eagle     Bull    1:0
3   Eagle     Snake   0:2
4   Bull      Eagle   0:1
5   Bull      Bull    —
6   Bull      Snake   3:4
7   Snake     Eagle   2:0
8   Snake     Bull    4:3
9   Snake     Snake   —
```

This is not doubling question . This is just division of task and some derivative quesion.
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19944634/edit
In this question I do not wanna sorted data like in 19944634 post.

I just wanna GridView.Databind.
**When I perfom BindData function I receive a table output in browser with right number of columns butbut it is empty.** Why?

Code-behind:

```
namespace ASP_Web_Datagrid
{    
    public partial class GridView_FROM_SQL : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        DataTable dt_teams = new DataTable();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {      
                BindData();
                System.Data.DataTable dtUnique = dt_teams.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "name1");
                GridView1.DataSource = dtUnique;
                GridView1.DataBind();
                Message.Text = dt_teams.Rows.Count.ToString();

            }
        }

        public void BindData()
        {
            string constr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            const string queryTransaction = "SELECT name1 from Team_table";
            using (SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(queryTransaction, con1))
                {
                    con1.Open();                   
                    SqlDataAdapter ada;
                    ada = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);              
                    ada.Fill(dt_teams);
                    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();                   
                    con1.Close(); 
                }
            }
        }
```

Markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Eagle">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="litEagle" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Bull">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="litBull" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Snake">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="litSnake" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the literal text in the markup to bind to the column name in your data source, like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
              OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Eagle">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="litEagle" 
                             Text="<%# Eval('Team1') %>" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Bull">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="litBull" 
                             Text="<%# Eval('Team2') %>" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Snake">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="litSnake" 
                             Text="<%# Eval('Result') %>" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Thanks, **Karl Anderson**. I would test it later.

Comment: When I do <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="litSnake" Text="<%#Eval('Team1').ToString()%>"/> there is Error 1 Too many characters in character literal error. I add ToString. Because there would be another error

Comment: And Warning 1 Validation (ASP.Net): If this attribute value is enclosed in quotation marks, the quotation marks must match.

Comment: I understood "too many character" and I try bind not dt_unique with 5 rows but dt_teams with 25. This also not work.